# What is atom in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I would like to have a clear understanding, what is 'Atom' in LISP?
Due to lispworks, 'atom - any object that is not a cons.'.
But this definition is not enough clear for me.

For example, in the code below:

```
(cadr 
      (caddar (cddddr L)))
```

Is 'L' an atom? On the one hand, L is not an atom, because it is cons, because it is the list (if we are talking about object, which is associated with the symbol L).
On the other hand, if we are talking about 'L' itself (not about its content, but about the symbol 'L'), it is an atom, because it is not a cons.

I've tried to call function 'atom',

```
(atom L) => NIL
(atom `L) => T
```

but still I have no clue... Please, help!

So the final question: in the code above, 'L' is an atom, or not?

---

P.S. I'm asking this question due to LISP course at my university, where we have a definition of 'simple expression' - it is an expression, which is atom or function call of one or two atomic parameters. Therefore I wonder if expression `(cddddr L)` is simple, which depends on whether 'L' is atomic parameter or not.

Comment: Atom is equivalent to `(not cons)`, that is, a singular value, not a pair. The function you're calling is a predicate, which tells you whether some value is an atom or not. http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_atom.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the one hand, L is not an atom, because it is cons, because it is the list (if we are talking about object, which is associated with the symbol L).

You are talking here about the meaning of the code being executed, its semantics. `L` here stands for a value, which is a list in your tests. At runtime you can inspect values and ask about their types.

> On the other hand, if we are talking about 'L' itself (not about its content, but about the symbol 'L'), it is an atom, because it is not a cons.

Here you are looking at the types of the values that make up the syntax of your code, how it is being represented before even being evaluated (or compiled). You are manipulating a tree of symbols, one of them being `L`. In the source code, this is a symbol. It has no meaning by itself other than being a name.

#### Code is data

Lisp makes it easy to represent source code using values in the language itself, and easy to manipulate fragments of code at one point to build code that is executed later. This is often called homoiconicity, thought it is somewhat a touchy word because people don't always think the definition is  precise enough to be useful. Another saying is "code is data", something that most language designers and programmers will agree to be true.

Lisp code can be built at runtime as follows (`>` is the prompt of the REPL, what follows is the result of evaluation):

```
> (list 'defun 'foo (list 'l) (list 'car 'l))
(DEFUN FOO (L) (CAR L))
```

The resulting form happens to be valid Common Lisp code, not just a generic list of values. If you evaluate it with `(eval *)`, you will define a function named `FOO` that takes the first element of some list `L`.

NB. In Common Lisp the asterisk `*` is bound in the REPL to the last value being successfully returned.

Usually you don't build code like that, the Lisp *reader* turns a stream of characters into such a tree. For example:

```
> (read-from-string "(defun foo (l) (car l))")
(DEFUN FOO (L) (CAR L))
```

But the reader is called also implicitly in the REPL (that's the R in the acronym).

In such a tree of symbols, `L` is a symbol.

### Evaluation model

When you call function `FOO` after it has been defined, you are evaluating the body of `FOO` in a context where `L` is bound to some value. And the rule for evaluating a symbol is to lookup the value it is bound to, and return that. This is the semantics of the code, which the runtime implements for you.

If you are using a simple interpreter, maybe the symbol `L` is present somewhere at runtime and its binding is looked up. Usually the code is not interpreted like that, it is possible to analyze it and transform it in an efficient way, during compilation. The result of compilation probably does not manipulate symbols anymore here, it just manipulates CPU registers and memory.

In all cases, asking for the type of `L` at this point is by definition of the semantics just asking the type for whatever value is bound to `L` in the context it appears.

### An atom is anything that is not a cons cell

Really, the definition of `atom` is no more complex than that. A value in the language that is not a cons-cell is called an atom. This encompasses numbers, strings, everything.
Sometimes you evaluate a tree of symbols that happens to be code, but then the same rule applies.

### Simple expressions

> P.S. I'm asking this question due to LISP course at my university, where we have a definition of 'simple expression' - it is an expression, which is atom or function call of one or two atomic parameters. Therefore I wonder if expression (cddddr L) is simple, which depends on whether 'L' is atomic parameter or not.

In that course you are writing functions that analyze code. You are given a Lisp value and must decide if it is a simple expression or not.

You are not interested in any particular interpretation of the value being given, at no point you are going to traverse the value, see a  a symbol and try to resolve it to a value: you are checking if the *syntax* is a valid simple expression or not.

Note also that the definitions in your course might be a bit different than the one from any particular exising flavor (this is not necessarily Common Lisp, or Scheme, but a toy LISP dialect). Follow in priority the definitions from your course.

Answer (score 1):

Your Lisp course's private definition of "simple expression" is almost certainly rooted purely in syntax. The idea of "atomic parameter" means that it's not a compound expression. It probably has nothing to do with the run-time value!

Thus, I'm guessing, these are simple expressions:

```
(+ 1 2)
42
"abc"
```

whereas these are not:

```
(+ 1 (* 3 4)) ;; (* 3 4) is not an atomic parameter
(+ a b c)     ;; parameters atomic, but more than two
(foo)         ;; not simple: fewer than one parameter, not "one or two"
```

In light of the last counterexample, it would probably behoove them to revise their definition.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have a predicate which tells us if an object is not a *number*:

```
(not-number-p 3)               -> NIL
(not-number-p "string")        -> T
(let ((foo "another string))
  (not-number-p foo))          -> T
(not-number '(1 2 3))          -> T
(not-number (first '(1 2 3))   -> NIL
```

We can define that as:

```
(defun not-number-p (object)
  (not (numberp object))
```

Above is just the opposite of `NUMBERP`.

- `NUMBERP`       -> `T` if object is a number
- `NOT-NUMBER-P`  -> `NIL` if object is a number

Now imagine we have a predicate `NOT-CONS-P`, which tells us if an object is not a `CONS` cell.

```
(not-cons-p '(1 . 2))          -> NIL
(let ((c '(1 . 2)))
  (not-cons-p c))              -> NIL
(not-cons-p 3)                 -> T
(let ((n 4))
  (not-cons-p n))              -> T
(not-cons-p NIL)               -> T
(not-cons-p 'NIL)              -> T
(not-cons-p 'a-symbol)         -> T
(not-cons-p #\space)           -> T
```

The function `NOT-CONS-P` can be defined as:

```
(defun not-cons-p (object)
  (if (consp object)
      NIL
      T))
```

Or shorter:

```
(defun not-cons-p (object)
   (not (consp object))
```

**The function `NOT-CONS-P` is traditionally called `ATOM` in Lisp.**

In Common Lisp every object which is not a *cons cell* is called an *atom*. The function `ATOM` is a *predicate*.

See the Common Lisp HyperSpec: [Function Atom](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_atom.htm)

---

**Your question:**

```
(cadr  (caddar (cddddr L)))
Is 'L' an atom?
```

How would we know that? `L` is a variable. What is the value of `L`?

```
(let ((L 10))
  (atom L))            -> T

(let ((L (cons 1 2)))
  (atom L)             -> NIL
```

`(atom l)` answers this question:

-> is the value of `L` an *atom*

`(atom l)` **does not** answer this question:

-> is `L` an *atom*? `L` is a *variable* and in a function call the **value** of `L` is passed to the function `ATOM`.

If you want to ask if the *symbol* `L` is an *atom*, then you need to quote the *symbol*:

```
(atom 'L)          -> T
(atom (quote L))   -> T
```

**symbols are atoms**. Actually everything is an *atom*, with the exception of cons cells.